# Google Play website says I have certain apps installed that I do not. How to re-sync?

Tags: google-play-store, google

Here is an example. I do not have the Facebook for Android application install on my current device or any other device. Why does it continue to say I have it installed? Is there a way to re-sync Google Play?

- Nexus 6
- Android 7.0

[image]

Comment: Yes I have, but it is not currently installed and has not for sometime. This is just one example.

Comment: I am having this exact same error. Did you find a way around this?

Comment: @Aarmora no. I am wondering if it is apps on older phones?

Comment: I don't think that's the case with me. This happens to me a lot of the time when I just try to install an app from the google play web app.  So I can clearly see that I've never had this app installed before, I hit install, it says it installs and IS installed but then doesn't ever show up on my phone.

Comment: That sounds like the exact opposite of what is happening to me.

Answer (score 2):

Any app that you have installed ( including the ones you subsequently uninstalled ) will *always* show up when you sign in with the account you used to install

[Deleting android apps using my google play account on my commputer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/play/GX1VklgtjPk) explains further

> When you uninstall an app, it still STAYS on your app list.  That's done so you can find it again or install it on another device easily.  This can be very helpful to keep a list of apps you like but don't want on your phone all the time (like tools you only use a couple of times a year)

So re- sync will not help. Only way to not see that app is to sign in with a different account and use that account on your phone to install only those apps which you wish to see. Obvious disadvantage of doing this is you cannot access apps which you have previously paid for using a different account - see [How to transfer my purchased apps to another account](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/play/6oLZD3l8pYM)

Comment: The app is not in my app list, it just shows on Google Play.

Comment: [see best answer here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/mOfvmZDHkYw) - though this is fairly recent, i just tried and it doesn't work, so they're appears to be no way

Comment: The app is not in my app list, it just shows on Google Play. It is also not in the "my apps" list on Google play. It just says "installed".

Comment: That's strange. Did you have the *desk top version of app ever* installed?

Comment: No. How? There is a desktop version of Facebook for Android app that you can install from the Google Play store?

Comment: No not from play store , two *guesses* 1. You had probably installed Facebook on desktop and somehow that info gets linked play store ( i dont use it at all, so can't say much) 2. Other apps, ( you have Facebook as an example, i know), came *pre installed*  ( bloatware) with one of your devices?  I had Twitter preinstalled on of my devices and it shows up here on Google web version but *not* in play store history

Comment: I have a nexus 6 running android 7. Facebook didn't come pre-installed. Possibly on older devices from years ago? I have never use Facebook for work.

Comment: Going by my Twitter experience, it is possible that it was pre installed on earlier device. Related problem here with pre installed apps http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26192

Comment: I can confirm that it is not related to be preinstalled. Irrespective of whether the app is listed in Play Store > My apps & games > All; it will show up as "Installed" on the store website if it was installed in the past. I've quite an OCD about these things and could do nothing about it. I hope they fix this.

Comment: @varunyellina: Thanks. Maybe time to open a bug report? Not sure how that can be done, though

Comment: I remember this to be "the" behaviour right since my first device running 2.2 Eclair. It's just painful to see all those stupid apps I installed back then.